# Drawing a line through given points (spline) with R

Tags: r, splines, interpolation

I am given `x = c(50, 37, 25, 0)` and `y = c(30, 52, 65, 70)`. These are vectors containing the x and y coordinates of four points. I need to draw a smooth curve through all four points, and get the actual equation for this function.

How do I accomplish this with `R`?

I was reading the documentation for splines but given my lack of familiarity with the mathematics behind this, I got pretty confused.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = c(50, 37, 25, 0) 
y = c(30, 52, 65, 70)
plot(x, y)
```

You have to do a third degree polynom and than add a curve to the plot

```
  exe <- lm(y ~ I(x^3) + I(x^2) + x)
    curve(predict(exe, newdata = data.frame(x = x)), 0, 50, add = T)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly to draw the line, so thank you!  But I actually need the equation for the line, so that I can use it to generate a bunch of other points that lie on this line.  Could you help me with that?

Comment: do `summary(exe)` and you will get the coefficients of the equation

Comment: thank you so much for your help.  that worked perfectly!!